# Dump / Install HTML files with assetic in Symfony2

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, twig, assetic

This is more a technical question than a real problem so I don't know if it will be removed but I will ask it anyway.

So I am developing some platform using `Symfony2`, `AngularJS`, `RequireJS` and other tons of stuff I need, everything works with harmony and peace, but I want to create some panels in pure `HTML` (no twig files) so `AngularJS` can load it using `ngRoute`, but thoose files need to reside in `/web/partials` (for example) to be loaded correctly, because assetic wont generate thoose files inside `/bundles/foo/barbundle/partials/*.html` as they are not JS, CSS or Images...

The question is simple, is there any way to either force `AngularJS` to load TWIG templates as partials or forcing `Symfony2` assetic to dump my partials inside web folder?

I know that putting manually inside `/web` is enough to load everything I need and it is loading perfectly in production, but I want to keep some folder structure and keep all my frontend stuff in the same folder `/src/Foo/BarBundle/Resources/public/*`

**UPDATE**

I just saw that assets are installing my html files inside my bundle public folder, I don't know why it didn't work before but creating them inside `src/Foo/BarBundle/Resources/public/partials` and then `app/console assets:install --symlinks` links them to `/web/bundles/foobar/partials`, as I say, it didn't work before...

But the question about loading twig files with AngularJS still there.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can easily load your partials from the web folder using `app/console assets:install --symlink` to place partials and set the good asset path in your angular routing (like `/web/bundles/foobar/partials/*.html`).

Load twig templates using Angular ngRouter is not a good thing, because PHP is an  interpreted language. But load your partials in a Twig template using ngView is possible (PHP is interpreted, and after you switch markup with angular routes).